# Mustache.js render a matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, mustache

How do I render a matrix in Mustache.js?

Unfortunally I can not change the structure of the Matrix.

The following Matrix:

```
    var DiskMakerModels = [
        [ "Blue", "WD" ],
        [ "Green", "WD" ],
        [ "Black", "WD" ],
        [ "Purple", "WD" ],
        [ "Red", "WD" ],
        [ "Red Pro", "WD" ],
        [ "Gold", "WD" ],
        [ "Barracuda", "Seagate" ],
        [ "Firecuda", "Seagate" ],
        [ "Ironwolf", "Seagate" ],
        [ "Skyhawk", "Seagate" ]
    ];
```

Needs to be rendered into the following template:

```
<script id="tableTemplate" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    {{#rows}}
        <div class="list-item noPrint" dir="ltr">
            <input type="readonly" class="rowNum" value="1">
            <button onclick="addTableElement(this)">+</button>
            <input type="text" class="txtInp" value="{{.[0]}}">
            <input type="text" class="txtInp" value="{{.[1]}}">
            <button onClick="removeTableElement(this);">-</button>
        </div>
    {{/rows}}
</script>
```

where: `{{.[0]}}` and `{{.[1]}}` should be the first and second items of the specific row.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following tweak should do the trick:

```
<script id="tableTemplate" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
    {{#rows}}
        <div class="list-item noPrint" dir="ltr">
            <input type="readonly" class="rowNum" value="1">
            <button onclick="addTableElement(this)">+</button>
            {{#.}}
                <input type="text" class="txtInp" value="{{.}}">
            {{/.}}
            <button onClick="removeTableElement(this);">-</button>
        </div>
    {{/rows}}
</script>
```

I've tested it out and it seems to work, though I'm running a php version of mustache so your mileage may vary.